# Kibana is not coming up when i have AWS Elasticsearch service with 5.1 version with separate installation of kibana 5.1.1 with x-pack

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-x-pack

I am using AWS Elasticsearch service with 5.1 version.
I have separate installation of kibana 5.1.1 with x-pack.
My Kibana is not coming up, giving Authorization Exception

As per forum https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=248200, Amazon ES does not support x-pack plugin.
Now How do i create users in kibana

Below are the Logs on Kibana Terminal:

```
> log [07:54:06.223] [error][status][plugin:xpack_main@5.1.1] Status
> changed from yellow to red – Authorization Exception log
> [07:54:06.224] [error][status][plugin:graph@5.1.1] Status changed from
> yellow to red – Authorization Exception log [07:54:06.224]
> [error][status][plugin:reporting@5.1.1] Status changed from yellow to
> red – Authorization Exception log [07:54:06.225]
> [error][status][plugin:elasticsearch@5.1.1] Status changed from yellow
> to red – Authorization Exception log [07:54:06.230]
> [error][status][plugin:security@5.1.1] Status changed from
> uninitialized to red – Authorization Exception log [07:54:06.231]
> [warning][security] Generating a random key for
> xpack.security.encryptionKey. To prevent sessions from being
> invalidated on restart, please set xpack.security.encryptionKey in
> kibana.yml log [07:54:06.234] [warning][security] Session cookies will
> be transmitted over insecure connections. This is not recommended. log
> [07:54:06.279] [error][status][plugin:profiler@5.1.1] Status changed
> from uninitialized to red – Authorization Exception
```